# Share login details on multiple websites in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, login, customer-session, customer-login

I have two websites on one Magento with two different domains. Now, when customers log in to one domain and they go to the rest domain, they must log in again. Is there any way to share log in, So, they don't need to log in again?

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: any success on above issue.

Comment: I don't have any issue for it.

Comment: you mean to say u achieved it above solution, i am also looking for similar solution

Comment: Sorry, I mean I don't have a solution for it yet. You can refer:
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/customers/customer-configuration.html